# ScrollView with sub RelativeLayout does not scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I have a `ScrollView` with 1 `RelativeLayout` which has 3 sub `RelativeLayouts`:

[image]

I set top `RelativeLayout` to `alignParentTop="true"`,

The bottom `RelativeLayout` to `alignParentBottom="true"`.

The middle layout to

```
android:layout_below="@id/topLayout"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
```

**Problem:** Scrollview does not scroll when screen is small, instead topLayout stays at top and bottomLayout stays at the bottom. The middle layout gets small and (even lost) as like below:

[image]

**Desired:** I want topLayout stay at top and bottomLayout stay at bottom. But when there is no space there must be scroll so they middle layout must not get lost.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.jemshit.itu.fragments.TakeAttendanceFragment"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/halfClassic"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/halfClassic"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/halfClassic"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/halfClassic">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutWeekChoice"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerWeekChoice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSetDate"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonSetDate"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSetDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Set Date"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/halfClassic"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/halfClassic"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinnerWeekChoice"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCardRead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutWeekChoice"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layoutShowAttendance"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageCard"
                android:src="@drawable/std_card"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textWarningCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Checking..."
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageCard"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutShowAttendance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/halfClassic"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAttended"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Attended: "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNotAttended"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Not Attended: "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textAttended"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonManualAttendance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Manual Attendance"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/textNotAttended"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/halfClassic"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/halfClassic"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Note:** I do not want to use `LinearLayout` with `weight="1"` which will make my 3 layouts same height

**EDIT:** now `ScollView` scrolls with new code below but my bottom `TextViews` get lost:

[image]

**Code Updated:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.jemshit.itu.fragments.TakeAttendanceFragment"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/halfClassic"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/halfClassic"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/halfClassic"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/halfClassic">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutWeekChoice"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerWeekChoice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSetDate"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonSetDate"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSetDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Set Date"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/halfClassic"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/halfClassic"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinnerWeekChoice"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCardRead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutWeekChoice"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageCard"
                android:src="@drawable/std_card"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textWarningCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Checking..."
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageCard"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutShowAttendance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/halfClassic"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutCardRead"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAttended"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Attended: "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textNotAttended"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNotAttended"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Not Attended: "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonManualAttendance" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonManualAttendance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Manual Attendance"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/halfClassic"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/halfClassic"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your parents `RelativeLayout` height to `wrap_content`. `Match_parent` needs only `ScrollView`, everything inside it can spend all the space it needs.

Comment: Just noticed that you set `below` and `above` attributes to the middle layout. Use only `below` attribute for middle and bottom layouts.

Comment: yes does make scroll, but my texts in bottomLayout get lost when it scrolls. I have 2 texts and 1 button. Button set to alignParentBottom, other 2 texts set to layout_above="button" and layout_above="text2". : http://postimg.org/image/mt186ftfl/ What might be problem

Comment: No need for `alignParentBottom` - layout will stretch for contain full-size texts and button. Just place top text with `alignParentTop` and other views with `above` attributes. And it would be great if you edit your question by writing code you are already have.

Comment: i could do that, but in that way my bottom text and button will be at top of bottomLayout , and there will be white space at bottom of screen

Comment: You can replace your parent `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation, and set `weight=1` attribute for middle layout. Of course, in that way `below` attribute would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

From your 2nd relative layout,that is layoutcard remove `android:layout_above="@+id/layoutShowAttendance"`

and from layoutShowAttendance remove 
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
and add  `android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCardRead"` to layoutShowAttendance

It will work.

Comment: but then my bottom layout will not be at the bottom of screen, there will be white space at bottom of screen, right?

Comment: If you will run it on  bigger screen,there will be  a white space at bottom. but if you will set your layout at bottom it will not scroll and if you will set a bigger image it will even overlap your image.